# TabNavigator pass different param from each screen to StackNavigator header

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have Question. How can I pass specific param from each screen to the StackNavigator header in order to come out different kind of components when reached the screen.

I have done some research about this kind of question, but there are not much info that can help me. So I posted here to find some help, hope there are someone who can guide me. Thanks a lot.

```
const mainNav = TabNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: HomeScreen,
    param:{
      tabval:1
    }
  },
  Live: {
   screen: LiveScreen,
   param:{
      tabval:2
    }
  },
  Radio: {
   screen: RadioScreen,
   param:{
      tabval:3
    }
  },
} );

function DifferentComponents(tabval){
  if(tabval == 1){
    //do something
  }else if(tabval == 2){
    //do something
  }else{
    //do something
  }
}

export const mainStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: mainNav,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: (
        <View style={styles.topnavscrollview}>
          <View style={{width:300}}>
            <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
              {this.DifferentComponents(tabval)} <-- Change this when switch to Live tab or others
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
      ),
    },
  },
  Content: { screen: ContentScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the custom header value as a prop to the component.
Then put something like this at the top the component that you want to customize the header for:

```
class Home extends React.Component {    

  // dynamically set header title when component mounts
  static navigationOptions = (props) => {
    const title = props.myTitleForThisComponent;
    return { title }
  }

  render(){
  // render stuff..
  }
}
```

When you navigate to the component via a StackNavigator link, any props that you pass into the component will be available as `this.props.navigation.state.params`.

For example, if you navigate to your component via StackNavigator like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(
    'Home',
     /* below passes into the "Home" component as: this.props.navigation.state.params.title */
     { myCustomTitle: "hello there" }
)}
```

Then you can create a custom title for the `Home` page component like this:

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { myCustomTitle } = navigation.state.params;
    return { title: `${myCustomTitle} !!`}
  }
```

> hello there !!

*Note*: when you define your `StackNavigator`, you do *not need* to include the option `navigationOptions.title`, since you are add it dynamically when the component mounts.
However, you can provide generic `navigationOptions` values within the StackNavigator definition, to provide a "default" values for components that do not add/re-write them dynamically.