# React Native - Track Screen react-naviagtion

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation for navigate screen. I used nested navigation, `TabNavigator` and `StackNavigator`. I would like to track the screen inside `HeaderCustom` so i can call different function when reached different screen.

Navi.js

```
import TopNavHeader from '../App/Components/HeaderCustom';
const mainNav = TabNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Live: {
   screen: LiveScreen,
  },
  Radio: {
   screen: RadioScreen,
  },
} );

export const mainStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: mainNav,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: (
        <HeaderCustom/>
      ),
    },
  },
  Content: { screen: ContentScreen },
});
```

HeaderCustom.js

```
class HeaderCustom extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    _CallDiffFunc(){
     if(screen == "home"){
      //do something
     }else{
      //do something
     }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.topcontainer}>
                <Icon />
                <Icon />
                <Icon />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = HeaderCustom;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => HeaderCustom);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigationOptions` prop can be a function that takes `navigation` as parameter.

**Example**

```
export const mainStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: mainNav },
  Content: { screen: ContentScreen },
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    header: (
      <HeaderCustom routeName={navigation.state.routeName}/>
    )
  }),
});
```

---

```
class HeaderCustom extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log(props.routeName); // Will log current Route's name 
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.topcontainer}>
                <Icon />
                <Icon />
                <Icon />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = HeaderCustom;
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I tried your answer, but the `console.log(props.routeName); ` only give me `Home`. When I swipe to change screen, `props.routeName` not giving me the right. Any idea ?

Comment: Update your question with the new code you tried. You need to set navigationOptions for every screen. If you set it like my example it will be available for every screen.

Comment: actually i would like to do something when tab is change , i have ask another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638454/tabnavigator-pass-different-param-from-each-screen-to-stacknavigator-header but no one answer, so i think is there another way to do this, then i ask this current question.

Comment: The solution is same for that question too. Rather than passing a new param checking routeName is more reliable. Read the navigation like I showed in my example and render header component accordingly.

Comment: my header is fixed one for all screen, but some subcontent is follow the screen. So I try to do is when changing screen, trigger and change the subcontent inside header.

Comment: Then set the navigationOptions for those screens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156904/discussion-between-im-happy-and-bennygenel).